# Getting `torch.utils.checkpoint.checkpoint` to early-stop

Tags: pytorch

The [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/checkpoint.html) for `torch.utils.checkpoint.checkpoint` say:

> Non-reentrant checkpoint stops recomputation as soon as all needed intermediate activations have been recomputed. This feature is enabled by default, but can be disabled with set_checkpoint_early_stop(). Reentrant checkpoint always recomputes function in its entirety during the backward pass.

Given the above, in the following snippet, in the `use_reentrant=False` section, I would expect `Bar.forward` to be called only once (on the first forward pass). I would also expect `Bar.backward` to be called never, since `Bar` is not in the computation graph of `L`. What am I missing?

```
import torch
from torch.utils.checkpoint import checkpoint
from torch.autograd import Function

class Foo(Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, X):
        print("Enter Foo forward")
        ctx.save_for_backward(X)
        print(f"Foo forward {X=}")
        return X

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grads):
        print("Enter Foo backward")
        X, = ctx.saved_tensors
        print(f"Foo backward {X=} {grads=}")
        return grads

class Bar(Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, X):
        print("Enter Bar forward")
        ctx.save_for_backward(X)
        print(f"Bar forward {X=}")
        return X

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grads):
        print("Enter Bar backward")
        X, = ctx.saved_tensors
        print(f"Bar backward {X=} {grads=}")
        return grads

def go(X):
    return Foo.apply(X), Bar.apply(X)

X = torch.randn((), requires_grad=True)

print("With use_reentrant=True")
L = checkpoint(go, X, use_reentrant=True)[0]
L.backward()

print("===")

print("With use_reentrant=False")
L = checkpoint(go, X, use_reentrant=False)[0]
L.backward()
```

Output:

```
With use_reentrant=True
Enter Foo forward
Foo forward X=tensor(-0.2438, requires_grad=True)
Enter Bar forward
Bar forward X=tensor(-0.2438, requires_grad=True)
Enter Foo forward
Foo forward X=tensor(-0.2438, requires_grad=True)
Enter Bar forward
Bar forward X=tensor(-0.2438, requires_grad=True)
Enter Bar backward
Bar backward X=(tensor(-0.2438, requires_grad=True),) grads=tensor(0.)
Enter Foo backward
Foo backward X=(tensor(-0.2438, requires_grad=True),) grads=tensor(1.)
===
With use_reentrant=False
Enter Foo forward
Foo forward X=tensor(-0.2438, requires_grad=True)
Enter Bar forward
Bar forward X=tensor(-0.2438, requires_grad=True)
Enter Foo backward
Enter Foo forward
Foo forward X=tensor(-0.2438, requires_grad=True)
Enter Bar forward
Bar forward X=tensor(-0.2438, requires_grad=True)
Foo backward X=(tensor(-0.2438, requires_grad=True),) grads=tensor(1.)
```

Comment: You can look at this if it can help: https://chat.openai.com/share/93757a8d-9fb2-427e-9459-815acd5cca3c